# Code is not executed in the correct order?

Tags: php

Code is designed to send a warning if no matches from the result set are found. However for some reason i found that my if statement `if($send_warning = true)` is not executed at the right time.

According to the code it should execute once the while loop finishes and it should take `$send_warning` variable to determine if the whole result set contained match or not and send warning accordingly.

Consider the following result set

```
1. 8.22.33.44
2. 9.88.44.33
3. 11.22.55.77
```

The `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` evaluates to `11.22.55.77`

So the loop starts obviously at the first index so it sets the `$send_warning` to true on the first iteration - however the loop has not yet finished. At this point the the if statement is already triggered. Which is wrong - as it should wait until the whole loop finishes.

What am i missing here ??

```
$send_warning = false;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($ip = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                var_dump($ip['ip_address']);
                echo "<br>";
                var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
                if($ip['ip_address'] == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) {
                        $send_warning = false;
                        break;
                        var_dump("not sending");
                } else {
                        var_dump("sending");
                        $send_warning = true;
                }
        }
        if($send_warning = true) {
                send($send);
        }

} else {
        //do nothing
}
```

Comment: `if($send_warning = true)` should be `if($send_warning === true)`

Comment: `$send_warning = true` _assigns_ the value `true` to the variable `$send_warning`.

Comment: @Dagon oh god.. yes.... a typical typo mistake. Thanks you for spotting ths